# How can i add Color of some specific String in Return Text

Tags: vb.net, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I Formatting Text in RDLC Report. This code is correct for justify Text but i also want to add diffrent color of some specific word in return Text.

Comment: What have you tried , can you please share ?

Comment: You first need a text format that can change the color of words.  Two practical formats are RTF and HTML.  So google "rdlc show rtf" and "rdlc show html".  Lots of hits, many programmers have tried this.  I don't see any that were successful at it at first glance.